# UITableViewのセルをスワイプした際のActionを実行した後に戻したい(メニューを閉じたい)

Tags: swift

### スワイプメニューを閉じたい

スワイプで`メニュー`を出し、Doneアクションでチェックマークをつけて、`メニュー`を閉じたいのですが、どうすればいいですか？

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: UIContextualAction.Style.normal, title: "Done") { (action, view, completionHandler) in
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath)
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
    }
    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIContextualAction`のインスタンス作成時に渡す`handler:`クロージャーの実装方法が誤っています。処理が全て完了した後には、必ず`completionHandler`を呼んでやらないといけません。

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: UIContextualAction.Style.normal, title: "Done") { (_, _, completionHandler) in
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at:indexPath)
            cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark
            completionHandler(true) //<-actionが実行された場合、`true`を渡す
        }
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。completionHandlerは意味のあるものだったのですね。